# Changing Type from Content To Global or VDC Drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views

I'm using Drupal 7 with the view_database_connector module. I'm currently working with a view that consists of a table displaying database information. My goal is to have a field with action buttons corresponding to each row, such as delete.

I am not allowed to use global php as a field.

I've attempted to make a custom module following this. I can currently use this module on content tables, however, when I try to use it on my view_database_connector table, I'm unable to add it as a field, since it's not apart of the same group.

Here's where I set up the information for making the action:

```
function mymodule_views_data_alter(&$data) {
  // debug($data['node']);
  $data['node']['actions'] = array(
    'title' => t('Actions'),
    'help' => t('Clickable links to actions a user may perform on a Node.'),
    'field' => array(
      'handler' => 'mymodule_views_handler_field_actions',
      'group' => 'Content',
      'click sortable' => FALSE,
    ),
  );
}
```

I've tried deleting Content, changing it to global, and changing it to the VDC type, but none of that changes it into Global or VDC.

Alternatively, if there's an easier way just to hook into a field that has a button to run my code which will download a file, that could circumvent this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to create this feature on your own - it already exists in views. There is a field type with actions as delete.

Other option is to use option called "rewrite value of this field" (or similar). With it you can make your field from views interface, and totally rewrite it's output. You can use token and some of them for sure contains node id, so you can use it to generate link to node deleting/editing/viewing pages.